# Python: syntax when adding parameters in cmd

Tags: python, shell, command-line, tagging

I followed the instructions from imagga to run a python script to auto tag multiple images with keywords at once using a 3rd party API (called imagga)
In the required script I have to add 3rd API Key and input and output parameters when running the script. (input is the folder containing the images and output is the folder to contain the results the script generates)
But I'm not a programmer, I don't know how to write the syntax correctly.
That's why the code can't run properly, and it shows an error saying I have to add two parameters: input and output
I'm hoping someone can give me a clear syntax example in cmd so I can run this script properly.
This is a 3rd party guide (imagga)
`https://imagga.com/blog/batch-image-processing-from-local-folder-using-imagga-api/`
(I added API key and API secret as instructions)
This is the original script code from imagga. (line 98 99 105 106)
`https://bitbucket.org/snippets/imaggateam/LL6dd`
I saved script as: `tag.py`
I try to run in cmd with this prompt: `tag.py`
But cmd sent me an error that I need add input and output arguments

I am trying to successfully launch a python script to automatically tag images in a local folder and export the results to another local folder

Comment: Glad this is resolved. In the future, please put a [mre] in your question. Links to external resources are fine but they should only be *an addition* to the code in your question. Also, giving *the exact command* you tried to run will make it easier for people to spot problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the script you provided, to run it with the required input and output parameters, you would use the following syntax in your command prompt (cmd):

```
python3 tag.py <input_folder_path> <output_folder_path>
```

Replace `<input_folder_path>` with the path to the folder containing the images you want to tag, and `<output_folder_path>` with the path to the folder where you want the script to save the results. Make sure to remove the angle brackets (`<` and `>`) when you replace these with your actual folder paths.

Comment: Thank you very much. I dont remove < and >. It worked according to your instructions. Thank you very much! (I much remove python3 to run, dont know why, but it work now) :D

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I didn't mention it, but if you're on Windows you simply need to use `python tag.py <input_folder_path> <output_folder_path>`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the script you link to, you need to give a directory containing your input and a directory that should contain the output like this:

```
> tag.py <input-dir> <output-dir>
```

Where both `<input-dir>` and `<output-dir>` are existing directories on your machine.

I believe running `tag.py --help` should print (among other things) something like:

```
<input>     The input - a folder containing images
<output>    The output - a folder to output the results
```

The angle brackets are part of the placeholder. This servers to differentiate `<mandatory args>` from `[optional args]`. This convention is mostly (though not always) followed in the *NIX world.
You would write something like:

```
> tag.py C:\my\input_dir C:\my\output_dir
```

Comment: The < and > signs are the problem. I left it out of the command and now it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: @LinhSonNguyen I failed to make clear that the angle brackets are part of the placeholder. I added some more explanation. I'm glad you made it work.